# How to output potentially multi-line environment variables from the output of env system command?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, environment-variables

I am having issues trying to parse / grep / pcregrep potentially multiple line environment variable values from the output of the env system command.  I am trying to get just the variables that start with a certain prefix that may or not be multiple lines.  So far I have been trying variants of this (with a lookahead):

```
env | pcregrep -M '^PREFIX_\S+\=[\S\s]+(?=^\S+\=.*$)'
```

But the above returns everything.  I think it is because the middle pattern is greedy with newlines, but I don't know how to get around that.  My problem is that I have no known end pattern, except the start of another variable pattern.

Does anyone know how I might be able to accomplish this task?  Thanks for any information you can provide!

Comment: Use non-greedy quantifier, `+?` or `*?`

Comment: Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew!!  Just tried that with the above pattern and it worked perfectly.